# Vue2.js - Use a custom component in custom plugin - how to pass props?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to make a plugin just to show a modal div with some custom personalization, so i thought of a plugin with a custom component. The idea is to call the plugin that should show the modal box (the component) but i cannot understand how to pass plugin methods props to the component.

I have this plugin

```
import Modal from './components/Modal'

const ModalComponent = {
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.component('modal', Modal)

    Vue.mixin({
      data () {
        return {
          status: null,
          modalMessage: null,
          show: false
        }
      },
      component: {
        Modal
      },
      methods: {
        setMessage (status, modalMessage) {

          console.log(status)
          console.log(modalMessage)
          this.status = status
          this.modalMessage = modalMessage
          this.show = true

        }
      }
    })
  }

}

export default ModalComponent
```

i can call the plugin in my other components in this way `this.setMessage(res.status, res.message)`

The component is this

```
<template>
    <b-modal
      v-model="show"
      centered
      cancel-disabled
      :title="title"
      :header-bg-variant="header_bg"
    ><p class="my-4">{{modalMessage}}</p>
    </b-modal>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: "modal",
    data() {

        return {
            show: false,
            title: null,
            modalMessage: null,
            header_bg: null
        }
    },
    props: {
            show: Boolean,
            title: String,
            modalMessage: String,
            header_bg: String
    }

}
</script>
```

How can i tell the component to show using props from the plugin? I miss the passage to send props to it when using the plugin methods

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your plugin doesn't generate any element. You're creating a method on every component using the mixin, but this will assume that *every* one of your components' templates has a `<Modal :status="status" :modalMessage="modalMessage" :show="true" />`

#### I would suggest a different approach...

in your main template, add the instance of the modal. Then you can use a global state of some sort. I prefer using `vuex` for this, since you can use the vuex state to mange the props, and use a globally available action (`commit`) with the desired payload. Alternatively, you can use the vue internals to modify state, but if you're already using vuex, this likely the easiest option.